# Is there a way to have a go back link that reloads the page so as to not display a previously opened modal?

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a contact form modal that pops up and sends the user to a results page. I want to have a link on the results page that will send the user back to the page they were looking at. The problem is that when they go back the modal contact form is still open. How can I force reload whatever page they were coming from? I am using a servlet if that matters.

```
<div class = "modal fade" id = "contact" role = "dialog">
        <div class = "modal-dialog">
            <div class = "modal-content">
                <form class = "form-horizontal" action="Servlet" method="get">
                    <div class = "modal-header">
                        <h4>Contact Site</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "modal-body">
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <label for = "contact-name" class = "col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
                            <div class = "col-lg-10">
                                <input type = "text" name="name" class = "form-control" id = "contact-name" placeholder="John Doe">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <label for = "contact-email" class = "col-lg-2 control-label">Email Address</label>
                            <div class = "col-lg-10">
                                <input type = "email" name = "emailAddress" class = "form-control" id = "contact-email" placeholder="johndoe@gmail.com">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <label for = "contact-msg" class = "col-lg-2 control-label">Message</label>
                            <div class = "col-lg-10">
                                <textarea class = "form-control" name = "message" id = "contact-msg" rows = "8"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" name="submitHTML" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss = "modal">Cancel</button>
                        <input id="formID" name="formID" value="contact" type="hidden"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So far this is what I have for the back button

```
<div class="container startOverButtonDIV">
    <div class = "row">
            <a class = "btn btn-primary" href="javascript:history.back()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></i> Go back to previous page</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there an actual page refresh going on? Or is it all javascript?

Comment: There is bootstrap js, but it ends up redirecting the user to a new web page (new url) when the form is submitted. Does that answer your question?

Comment: What is causing the modal to pop up in the first place? If you redirect them from the results page back to where they came from originally, (via a url not the browser back) I don't think the modal would stay open.

Comment: Twitter bootstrap is causing the modal to come up on the first page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the javascript history to go back, you are going to run into problems like this. If you want to redirect them to the page with a fresh state, use a direct url.

Well, I don't entirely understand the situation because I don't know how/what/why the modal is trigged, but, you could always just pass something in the URL to tell your web server to not trigger the modal.

So when redirecting the user, use a URL like, http://domain.com/url?modal=0
Then using whatever web setup you have, retrieve the GET variable and test for '0', in the case that it is 0, simply do not output the HTML for the modal. (or better yet find a way to not trigger the modal with javascript.)

Comment: I've updated my post with the HTML. The modal is triggered by a contact button on web page #1. The form submits and goes to web page #2. I have a back button on web page #2 that returns the user to webpage #1, with the form still open.

Comment: I added something to the beginning of my answer, I think that is why you are having this problem.